# a problem with Alphabet Phonetic in Longman dictionary

Tags: phonetics

I know vowels have short and long sounds. In the [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/howtouse.html) it has been displayed.  But on this webpage, I don’t know what is the difference between /ɪ/ and /i/ and /i:/ ? (for example in “bit” and “happy” and “which”)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Longman dictionary gives phonemic transcriptions. These are intended as a guide for people who know the sounds of English rather than a detailed description of the articulation.

The vowels /ɪ/ and /i/ are both close (or high) vowels (the tongue is held quite high in the mouth) and the are both front vowels (the highest point of the tongue is forward in the mouth).  The vowel /i/ is slightly higher and more forward than /ɪ/.

This means that /ɪ/ is slightly more relaxed than /i/.  The dots indicate length, /i:/ is a longer vowel sound than /i/.

The difference is the difference between "Bit" and "Beat".  There is both a difference in the length of the vowel, and the actual sound it makes. The difference is phonemic. Which means that if you use the very high and fronted vowel /i/ and say /bit/ instead of /bɪt/ some speakers will hear you say  /bi:t/. For correct pronunciation you need to practice these vowel sounds.

Answer (score 3):

/i:/ is very high and fronted. It's the sound in "see" and "fleece". In British English, it is also longer than /ɪ/. (In American English, the length difference is not significant).

/ɪ/ is more central, not as high as /i:/, and not as front. It's the sound in "sit" and "kit".

/i/ is not a separate sound. Longman's uses it to indicate that *some* speakers use /i:/ and other use /ɪ/.

Comment: Great answer! By the way I am not sure why you wrote _"see" and FLEECE_ and _"sit" and KIT_. I edited those words to make them more consistent, unless you did mean to distinguish between "see" and "fleece", "sit" and "kit".

Comment: I capitalized them because FLEECE and KIT are part of the [standard lexical set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) for English, and are usually capitalized when used as examples. But I don't mind that you've edited them to be consistent.